# I can't save monkeygtd on firefox

Tags: firefox, tiddlywiki, gtd

The firefox's version is 38.0.

When I try to save the monkeygtd based on tiddlywiki, it reports below. 
It's not possible to save changes. Possible reasons include:
- your browser doesn't support saving (Firefox, Internet Explorer, Safari and Opera all work if properly configured)
- the pathname to your TiddlyWiki file contains illegal characters
- the TiddlyWiki HTML file has been moved or renamed

Is there any specific setting on firefox?

Comment: What is the code you are trying to run?  You can edit your question to add your code.

Comment: There is no code. I got a empty monkeygtd from http://mgsd.tiddlyspot.com/, then open it with firefox. When I press 'save', it reports the error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from there 
https://www.mail-archive.com/gtd-tiddlywiki@googlegroups.com/msg01979.html

Paste here:

1. Open this web-page from Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tiddlyfox/?src=search
2. Install the TiddlyFox extension for Firefox
3. Re-start Firefox